# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'position' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing a function which changes states from Parent Component to Second Component and then Second Component to Third Component and calling from it.

This results in the following error:

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'position' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Following is my code for reference:

```
export class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      address: '',
      position: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
      },
    };
    this.locationChangeHandler = this.locationChangeHandler.bind(this);
  }

  locationChangeHandler({ position, address, places }) {
    // Set new location
    this.setState({ position, address });
  }

  render(){

<SecondComponent locationChangeHandler={this.locationChangeHandler}/>

}
```

Second Component:

```
<ThirdComponent locationChangeHandler={locationChangeHandler}/>
```

Third Component:

```
<FourthComponent onChange={locationChangeHandler()}/>
```

How do I resolve this? I am relatively new to ReactJs and would appreciate all help.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: @MathewsSunny please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you change locationChangeHandler function like this

```
locationChangeHandler(loc) {
    // Set new location
        if(loc && loc.position && loc.address)
        this.setState({ position: loc.position, address: loc.address });
  }
```